# How to change background on DataGridCell depending on bound complex object value

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, datagrid, datatrigger

This is what I want to accomplish: 
The bound collection on a DataGridd contain instances of RowModel, illustrated below (minimalized for simplicity), and then RowModel can contain instances of ValidationClass.

```
public class RowModel
{
    public int RowId { get; set; }
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ValidationClass> Validations { get; set; }
}

public class ValidationClass
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string SourceColumn { get; set; }
    public string ErrorText { get; set; }
}
```

The ValidationClass.SourceColumns references to the columns in RowModel that has an error.
the Tag property of the ValidationClass can be either "Critical" or "Warning".

The validations are grabbed from a database which is populated from an external validator. 
And if an validation error has occured for one or more of the columns the Collection is filled with one ValidationClass per error.

Now, if I want to set a Red background color on a cell which has a Critical error and a Yellow background on a cell that has a Warning, how can I do that?

DataTriggers or Converters, or something else? 
Need some help to point me in the right direction.

EDIT: To clearify, I'm using C# .net4 WPF DataGrid for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it using converters.

Having a DataGrid with specified columns, each of them defined like this:

```
<MyOwn:CustomDataGridColumn Header="Column1Header" Name="Column1" ElementStyle="{StaticResource ElementStyleWithMultiConverterAndTriggers}">
    <MyOwn:CustomDataGridColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="RowModel.ColumnName"  ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Validators:CustomCellDataInfoValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
    </MyOwn:CustomDataGridColumn.Binding>
</MyOwn:CustomDataGridColumn>
```

I then attached a style with DataTriggers looking like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="ElementStyleWithMultiConverterAndTriggers">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Utils:ErrorTypeConverter x:Key="ErrorTypeConverter"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Padding" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="Critical" >
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ErrorTypeConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}" Path="Column.Name"/>
                    <Binding Path="RowModel" /> <!--Sending the whole row object as one of the parameters to the converter-->
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>             
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Value="Warning" >
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ErrorTypeConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}" Path="Column.Name"/>
                    <Binding Path="RowModel" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>                              
        </DataTrigger>            
    </Style.Triggers>        
</Style>
```

The MultiValueConverter looks like this.

```
public class ErrorTypeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var rowObject = values[1] as RowModel;
        var param = values[0].ToString();
        if (rowObject == null) return "";
        if (rowObject.ValidationClass.Any())
        {
            var validationErrors = rowObject.ValidationClass.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SourceColumn == param);
            if (validationErrors != null )
                return validationErrors.Tag; // Will return "Critical" or "Warning"
        }
        return "";
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This suite my needs but is a but heavy on a DataGrid with 1000+ rows in the search result. But it's better than nothing. Any improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

triggers and converters are both equaly valid for that problem. Here the solution with trigger:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag}" Value="Critical">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag}" Value="Warning">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however it does not help me much or I do not understand. The DataGrid is bound to a Collection that contain instaces of type 'RowModel'. Each instance of 'RowModel' then has a collection that contain instances of type 'ValidationClass'. Each 'ValidationClass' has a mapping to a prop in the 'RowModel' class. The above example would only work if the DataGrid's bound collection would contain instances of 'ValidationClass', right? Iwould like to have some input on how to solve this with when the collection has instaces of 'RowModel' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event. There you can check for your condition and set the color using -

> e.CellStyle.BackColor

See the msdn sample in the link.

Comment: Unfortunately the CellFormatting event does not apply for .net4 wpf DataGrid controller, so that didn't work for me.